# Scanf complie errors ;I need to understand the errors that occured as i compiled this program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 16
int main(void)
{
 int borrow=0;
 int radix=2;
 int i=0;
 int x[N]={0};
 int y[N]={0};
 int di[N]={0};
 int hex1;
 int hex2;
 int j;

 scanf("%i,%i,&hex1,&hex2");

//error: warning: format ‘%i’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]

 scanf("%i,%i,&hex1,&hex2");//
           ^

//error2:format ‘%i’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]

scanf("%i,%i,&hex1,&hex2");//
              ^
}
```

Comment: and which part of the error message is not clear?

Comment: please add code formatting, hint: select code and press control + K

Comment: see the definition of scanf https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/scanf

Comment: If your editor have syntax highlighting, it should be *very* clear what the problem is. Take a closer look at the format ***string***... Where does it begin, ***where does it end?***

Answer (score 5):

Your `"` should close before you have your variables, then a comma, then the variables.

```
scanf("%i %i",&hex1,&hex2);
```

Comment: Here working example: https://onlinegdb.com/HJNfyGFO7 you can also use `scanf("%i,%i",&hex1,&hex2);` - with ","

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed to `scanf` must be provided *after* the format string, not within it:

Change

```
scanf("%i,%i,&hex1,&hex2");
```

to

```
scanf("%i,%i",&hex1,&hex2);
```

(Note the `"` shifted in front of the `,&hex1`-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax of your "scanf" =>   Scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y);

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 16
int main(void)
{
    int borrow=0;
    int radix=2;
    int i=0;
    int x[N]={0};
    int y[N]={0};
    int di[N]={0};
    int hex1;
    int hex2;
    int j;

    scanf("%i,%d",&hex1,&hex2);

//error: warning: format ‘%i’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]

    scanf("%i,%i",&hex1,&hex2);//


//error2:format ‘%i’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]

    scanf("%i,%i",&hex1,&hex2);//

}
```